# Как скачать аудиокнигу с торрента и склеить её в один mp3?

Tags: python

У меня канал с аудиокнигами. Хотелось бы автоматизировать процесс подготовки аудиокниги.
Есть VPS WinServ. Там я скачиваю аудиокниги с торрентов и потом в AIMP компилирую их в один файл mp3.
Можно ли написать скрипт, который будет скачивать аудиокнигу и джойнить все главы в один файл? Т.е. существует ли вообще такая возможность?
Желательно все это на python

*P.S.: Я полный нуб в кодинге, но очень стараюсь научиться*

Comment: rtorrent, например, умеет смотреть в определённый каталог и автоматически подхватывать помещаемые туда .torrent-файлы, а также [вызывать скрипт](https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent/wiki/Common-Tasks-in-rTorrent#send-email-for-completed-downloads) по завершении скачивания торрента

Answer (score 0):

Смотри в сторону ffmpeg. Возможно даже получится автоматически скармливать список mp3. Есть обёртка на [питоне](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python).

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:file1.mp3|file2.mp3" -acodec copy output.mp3
```

Comment: В эту сторону давно смотрел. Даже какое-то время использовал. Джойнит в разы быстрее, что любое ПО. 
Иногда путает порядок файлов, если тэги неправильно расставлены.
Но больше волнует именно автоматизация "торрент-компиляция".